# Delete 4x4 matrix at specific index

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have 50 4x4 matrices. I want to delete a matrix at specific index e.g. index 2, 12 and 34. I have tried  this but I am not getting the desired result:

```
 for i = 1:50
  index = true(length(AB));
  index([2,12,34]) = false;
  AB(:,:,i) = AB(:,:,index);
  end
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get the question. You have 50 matrices of size 4x4, stored in an array of dimension 4x4x50, right? Which values exactly do you want to delete? And what do you mean by delete? Remove completely from the array, or set to zero/false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are apparently using a 3D matrix `AB` of size `4 x 4 x 50`. Removing elements can be done like this:

```
index = [2 12 34];
AB(:,:,index) = [];
```

note that this will change your indices, since indices 2, 12 and 34  have been removed.

To set the element to 0 however:

```
index = [2 12 34];
AB(:,:,index) = 0;
```